# merge .wav and .avi file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, video

I have an wav sound file and I have avi video file in MATLAB,
I want to merge those files. 
I try to do this with audioread but the video was created with videowrite so i don't really know how to merge the files. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in matlab, if possible would be at such a high level of abstraction you might just as well do it outside of matlab, or have matlab do a system call to execute :

```
avconv -i original_video.avi -i some_audio.wav -c copy output_video.avi
```

where [avconv](https://libav.org/) is a standalone cross-platform media utility

Comment: +1 - There are no utilities in MATLAB that do combined audio and video processing.   It's either one or the other.  This is the easiest way to merge the two media together.  BTW Scott, your FFMPEG instructions saved my life.  I couldn't get it to compile with `libx264` until I saw your post.  Thanks!

Comment: hey Scott, i dont really understand your answer, what is this platform do? and what the system call from matlab make? thank you

Comment: First step : install and get running the video/audio utility software called avconv which is a free download from https://libav.org/download.html   Once you have avconv running, take your audio WAV file and the AVI video you mentioned and execute the above command at the command line.  All operating systems have a command line.  Once this works outside of matlab, only then lookup how to make system calls from matlab so you can issue a similar avconv command as a system call within matlab - good luck - let us know how you get on and if you need more tips - Welcome Aboard